# WMI Process Call Create will not Run Batch script properately

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

This is what i am trying to do:
I have a NLB Cluster. There are two machines on said cluster: **Node1** and **Node2**.
I have a third machine that is not in that, or any, cluster. This third machine is called: **Monitor1**

Once every hour, i would like to run a script to check if Node1 and Node2 are up.
This script will be run via TaskScheduler.
I am using the following command to execute the script on Node1 and Node2:

```
wmic /node:NODE1,NODE2 process call create "C:\ClusterCheck.bat"
```

The contents of the ClusterCheck.bat script is as follows:

```
NLB Query | findstr /i /R /C:"host . is stopped"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (ECHO %COMPUTERNAME%_down)>DOWN.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (ECHO %COMPUTERNAME%_up)>UP.txt
code here
```

When I use `wmic /node:"%1" process call create "C:\ClusterCheck.bat"` there is not output.
When I go into the server and manually double click the ClusterCheck.bat file, it gives me the appropriate output depending whether the node is up or down.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get those files to output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem, when you `wmic process call create` you should use prefix your command with `cmd /c`.

Next, you're right.  `wmic` doesn't display the resulting output of the remotely created process on your local console.  You'll either need to use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) which was designed for this sort of thing, or hack a workaround by piping the command output to a log file then reading the log file.  Something like the following script.

I'm not really clear, if this is going to be a scheduled task, why you're concerned with results being available to stdout.  I suspect you intend to redirect the output to a log of some sort.  So I put that in here as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "user=domainadmin"
set "pass=password"

for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do set "timestamp=%%I"
set "today=%timestamp:~0,8%"

set logfile=c:\users\me\Desktop\logs\%today%.log

if not exist "%logfile%" mkdir "%logfile%\.." 2>NUL
>>"%logfile%" echo %time%

for %%I in (NODE1 NODE2) do (
    (ping -n 1 %%I >NUL && (
        net use \\%%I /user:%user% %pass% >NUL 2>NUL
        wmic /node:%%I /user:%user% /password:%pass% process call create "cmd /c c:\clustercheck.bat >c:\cc.log"
        type \\%%I\c$\cc.log && del \\%%I\c$\cc.log
        net use \\%%I /delete >NUL 2>NUL
    ) || echo %%I unresponsive
)>>"%logfile%"

forfiles /p "%logfile%\.." /M *.log  /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

This should create `Desktop\logs` if it doesn't exist, then create or append to `Desktop\logs\YYYYMMDD.log` the output of `C:\clustercheck.bat` run on `NODE1` and `NODE2`.  Finally, it deletes log files that are over 30 days old.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about this, all the backslashes might need to be escaped with another backslash, like `\\\\%COMPUTERNAME%\\etc.`  I'll have to test this in the morning.

Comment: PSExec will not work properly with Task Scheduler. I have spent the better part of yesterday trying to make it work with no luck.

Comment: what is %CD::=$% supposed to mean?

Comment: `%CD::=$%` is the same as `%CD%` which is the current working directory.  The stuff in the middle substitutes colons for dollar signs.  So where `"%CD%" == "C:\Users"` you have `"%CD::=$%" == "C$\Users"`.

Comment: The above does not work. This is what i have typed in: wmic /node:<Node1> process call create "cmd /c C:\ClusterCheck.bat >> \\\\NetworkShare\\cc.log" >>type cc.log

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I got the information [from here](http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2009/05/episode-31-remote-command-execution.html), but I can't make it work either.  Logging the remote command to the remote machine then reading and deleting that log works, though.  I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: I know of Command Line Kung Foo and Ed Skoudis. I have already read that site. :P

Comment: @gmilic - is that what you needed?

Comment: The following line produced the output that i needed: wmic /node:%%I /user:%user% /password:%pass% process call create "cmd /c c:\clustercheck.bat >c:\cc.log". The output was placed in the directory of the remote server. This is what i wanted. Thank you!